# Can't build Textual IRC Client in XCode 4.5 on Mac OS X Lion 10.7

Tags: xcode, macos, build, osx-lion, xcode4.5

I'm trying to build [Textual IRC Client](http://www.codeux.com/textual/) from [source](https://github.com/Codeux/Textual/).

It worked for me in April, using the latest source and the latest XCode at that time, on the same OS X 10.7 computer. Now it does not work.

Example error messages

> - Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'NSArray *'
> - Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSDictionary *'
> - Expected method to write dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSMutableDictionary *'

I have turned off code signing in the build settings for all projects and targets (by setting `Code Signing Identity` to `Don't Code Sign`), otherwise the source is clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are because of new features introduced in the Mac OS X 10.8 SDK. Many of them are still [backwards compatible to Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html) though.

Textual's `Base SDK` build setting is set to `Current OS X`. Assuming that the other developers are on Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8, they will automatically use the (currently newest) 10.8 SDK. Even if the 10.8 SDK is installed on a 10.7 machine, the compiler will choose the 10.7 SDK because of this OS-dependent setting.

The fix: in Textual's build settings, change `Base SDK` to `OS X 10.8` or `Latest OS X (OS X 10.8)` to be able to use the new features.
Change the settings for all projects and confirm that the setting has been applied to their respective targets: *Main Project (Textual)*, *Blowfish Encryption Framework*, *Hyperlink Processor Framework*, *Blowfish Key Control Extension*, *Brag Spam Extension* and finally *System Profiler Extension*. Building *Textual (Standard Release)* should now work.

Related commit: [Conversion to modern Objective-C](https://github.com/Codeux/Textual/commit/a9dcfadbc7c52f6c5e862ae51b469b8df6212941) introducing 10.8 SDK features.

Comment: Even changing my SDK to 10.8 w/ xCode 4.5 on OSX 10.7 didn't help with this.  I still get the same 3 errors.  Any ideas?

Comment: @sjmh: did you change the *Base* SDK for all projects, and rebuild them? There's also a target level, but I think it's set to 10.6 by default.

Comment: I assume you mean for all the targets? I set it on the main project, which seemed to push the changes to all targets ( Build Frameworks, Clean Up, Version and the actual Textual target ).  Verified all the targets showed BaseSDK as Latest.  http://imgur.com/yKw0g.  My errors differ slightly ( I get a read on array error, read on dict, read on dict ), but seem to be related to same issue.

Comment: @smjh: I changed the Base SDK for all projects and confirmed that all targets had changed. Just verified it all from a clean git code checkout (including cleaning the build output), and that will work. (Assuming code signing has been disabled.)

Comment: Ok, I think I got what you meant - when you say 'all' projects, you mean you were opening the xcodeproj files for all the frameworks and extras provided in the Textual code and setting the BaseSDK in those as well? Is there any default way to do this via the main xcodeproj?

Comment: @sjmh: try clicking on the bar with "Main Project (Textual)", as seen [in your screenshot](http://imgur.com/yKw0g). It should open a dropdown with the different projects listed in my answer.